# Glyphicon on textbox disappears when selected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I was attempting to make a contact form for my site, [which can be previewed here.](https://theessemcraft.github.io/contact.html)

I used the Bootstrap Validator script to add verification icons/checks. However, when a textbox is selected that is used with the script, the validation icon disappears, like this:

[image: GIF of the issue]

This happens with the other boxes as well (except for the Subject box, which I didn't activate the validation script for.) How would I fix this? It worked on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TheEssem/pen/Xzrdwp), but not on my site.

[Here's the HTML for the page.](https://github.com/TheEssemCraft/theessemcraft.github.io/blob/f0a5d28c0ef8c706b49cfd48197e23a8f44616a0/contact.html)

HTML and CSS for just the form:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="https://formspree.io/example@example.com" method="post" id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

  <!-- Form Name -->
  <legend>Contact Me</legend>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Subject</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
        <input name="_subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text area -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Message <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="input" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Config -->
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="/contactthanks.html" />

  <!-- Required fields text -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="text-danger">* Required field</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-send"></span> Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

```
textarea {min-height:50px; resize:vertical;}
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Chrome Developer tools, you can see that adding the `:focus` pseudo-class to the element increases the `z-index` value of the `<input />` to 3, while the `.form-control-feedback` class maintains a `z-index` of 2.

[image: z-index of 3]

[image: z-index of 2]

Adding this selector appears to resolve it:

```
 input:focus ~ .form-control-feedback {
     z-index: 3;
 }
```

However, my guess is that this is the intended behavior in Bootstrap so the icon does not get in the way while the user is typing.

Comment: It doesn't work with the `textarea` element (message box), but that should be a quick fix. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-group .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

When you select an input, its icon goes behind cos of input's z index. Maybe try changin it ?